# JOIN data from two many-to-many SQL structures

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, many-to-many

I have established two many-to-many relationship 'structures'. One is for Films and their ambiences:

```
CREATE TABLE Films (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
PRIMARY KEY(id),    
Title VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Ambiences (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
ambienceName VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Films_Ambiences (
film_id INT NOT NULL,  
ambience_id INT NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (film_id, ambience_id),  
FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (ambience_id) REFERENCES Ambiences(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

The second one is for films and their specifics:

```
CREATE TABLE Specifics (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
specificName VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Films_Specifics (film_id INT NOT NULL,
specific_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (film_id,specific_id),
FOREIGN KEY (film_id)
REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (specific_id)
REFERENCES Specifics(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

I want to display all the results in one table (grouping by Title of the film). In other words, I want:

```
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| Title |  Ambiences   |    Specifics    |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
| film1 | funny, scary | aliens          |
| film2 | sad, scary   | knights, aliens |
| film3 | funny        | knights         |
| .     |              |                 |
| .     |              |                 |
| .     |              |                 |
+-------+--------------+-----------------+
```

With ambiences only, I used a few JOIN's and GROUP_CONCAT, like this:

```
SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ambiences
FROM Films AS f 
INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id           
INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
GROUP BY Title
```

With ambiences and specifics, I've tried using two GROUP_CONCAT's by didn't work out.
Here is an **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2643/3)** if you like.

An additional question here is, what if I had three or more many-to-many 'structures' and does it make sense?

**UPDATE**

I would also like to display Films which have no specifics. The solution proposed by @Kickstart doesn't seem to include that.

In other words I would like to display a film that is `funny, sad` but has no specifics.
Here is an updated **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bec0/1)** - You will find film4 is not being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISTINCT in the GROUP_CONCAT maybe

```
SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT specificName SEPARATOR ' ') AS specifics 
FROM Films AS f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id          
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Films_Specifics as fs ON f.id = fs.film_id          
LEFT OUTER JOIN Specifics AS s ON s.id = fs.specific_id
GROUP BY Title
```

Comment: The join condition for `Films_Specifics` should be `ON f.id = fs.film_id` (not `ON f.id = fa.film_id`).

Comment: @Kickstart, oh wait, looks like it works. I had a minor error in the Fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: @Kickstart And what if a film doesnt have any specifics? How do I display it then?

Comment: Yep, LEFT JOIN. Will add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Title,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(trim(AMBIENCENAME)),',')as Ambience,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(trim(specificName)),',')as Specifics
from Films f join 
Films_Ambiences fa on f.id = fa.film_id join
Ambiences a on a.id=fa.ambience_id join
Films_Specifics fs on fs.film_id = f.id join
Specifics s on s.id = fs.specific_id
group by title;
```

The result is nearly identical to the one you say you want save a few stray commas.

```
____________________________________________
|TITLE  |AMBIENCE       |SPECIFICS         |
|-------|---------------|------------------| 
|film1  |sad,           |aliens,           |
|film2  |sad,,happy,    |monsters,         |
|film3  |happy,         |monsters,,aliens, |
--------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT: NEW QUERY TO SATISFY UPDATE REQUIREMENT BELOW**

```
select Title,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(AMBIENCENAME),',')as Ambience,
CASE WHEN specificName is null then 'none' else GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(specificName ),',') END as Specifics
from 
Films f left join
Films_Ambiences fa on f.id = fa.film_id left join
Ambiences a on a.id=fa.ambience_id left join
Films_Specifics fs on fs.film_id = f.id left join
Specifics s on s.id = fs.specific_id
group by title;
```

Results:

```
__________________________________________
|TITLE  |AMBIENCE      |SPECIFICS        |
|----------------------------------------|
|film1  |sad,          |aliens,          |
|film2  |sad,,happy,   |monsters,        |
|film3  |happy,        |aliens,,monsters,|
|film4  |sad,,happy,   |none             |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: no problem! Thanks for showing me the SQLFiddle its a nifty tool!

Comment: I fixed my query so that it would satisfy the new requirements you posted an example of the results are under it!

Comment: :D @Legion U should read the anwser I already accepted :D. I am simply using LEFT JOIN insted of INNNER JOIN. ;).